# Show that the ring $R$ is commutative with unity with $x^n=x$ for all $x\in R$ has finite characteristic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose that $R$ commutative ring with unity and for all $x\in R$, $x^n=x$  and $n$ is fixed positive integer. Show that $R$ has finite characteristic.

How to prove that for unknown integer $n$. Also what is the possible numbers for characteristic . Is it the divisors of $n$.

I tried to start like this way :

$2x=(2x)^n=2^nx^n \Rightarrow (2^n-2)x=0 $. So this prove $R$ has finite characteristic, right ? but that will give me the possible values for characteristic for  $R$ is the divisors of $2^n-2$. I am so confused . I appreciate any hint. Thanks

I know in this type of ring every prime ideal is maximal, reduced, and Von Neumman ring.

Comment: What happens if you take $x=2 (:= 1+1)$

Comment: Did you also know that someone has proven a ring in which $x^n=x$ for a fixed $n>1$ is commutative, so that the commutativity hypothesis is redundant?  You may or may not: I was just throwing it out there. It's not really relevant for this question.

Comment: @rschwieb I didn't know that , I found on this amazing website some proofs when $n=2$ and $n=3$. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $x=1+1$.
Then
$$0=(1+1)^n-(1+1)=(2^n-2) \cdot 1$$
so that the ring has a characteristic dividing $2^n-2$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$$(1+1)^n=1+1$$
Therefore,
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\binom nj=0$$